# Copying apache binaries to path after installation from source safe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4

Currently on an Amazon ec2 instance. When I do

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

a lot of nice things are done for me. The httpd binaries are copied to the path

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX bin]$ ls /usr/sbin/ | grep "httpd"
httpd
httpd.event
httpd.worker
```

and `httpd` is made available to the service command:

```
sudo service httpd start
```

I recently decided to compile apache from source because I wanted more control over the configuration. This installed apache to `/usr/local/apache2/` with binaries in `bin/`, but not in the path. Is it safe/recommended for me to just use `cp`  to copy the binaried to `/usr/sbin`?

OR would it be better practice to add `/usr/local/apache2/bin` to the system path?

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat subjective, but I would suggest a third option, based not on experience with Apache specifically, but on general principles and lessons learned when compiling software that has a package manager component: symlink the binaries from the place where the installer puts them, into `/usr/local/sbin`, after verifying that this path has precedence over `/usr/sbin` by default.  It should.

Justifications/Advantages of this approach.

- default installation behavior still works, if you ever recompile
- default system path configuration, nothing changes there
- package manager subsequently updating the binaries it installed won't stomp your compiled binaries

The underlying theme here is that there are fewer changes, fewer things to remember or replicate, and fewer things to go wrong.